# how to let the kamailio support Edge Proxy?

Tags: sip, voip, sip-server, kamailio

As the RFC http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5626.txt describes , how can i extends a Edge Proxy by Kamailio ? should i write a module  , or just write the configure file ?

have any one already do it ,could give me some advice .

thanks .

Answer (score 2):

You could use an already configured instance - [SipWise](http://www.sipwise.com/products/spce/).

It's free, it's Kamailo based, it has an edge-proxy acting as a load-balancer at /etc/ngcp-config/templates/etc/kamailio/lb/kamailio.cfg.tt2, it's available as appliance and requires minimal configuration steps to run it with the basic features up.

You can use it directly, or you can just run it somewhere and take a look at the configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Why write a module? Edge proxy is a pretty much a SIP proxy for `REGISTER`s.

You could accomplish that with just the configuration routes.

Comment: have anybody already write the configure file ? so i can just use it . thanks .